# Faster way to fill NaN with best choice from groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fix some NaN values in a dataframe. My plan is to group the rows using two other related columns (a and b) and look at each group for the most frequent non-NaN value for column c -- and then use that to fill the NaN fields for the other rows in the group.

I have the code below, which works, but is very, very slow -- it's been running for a couple of hours now on an dataframe with approx 3 millions rows.

Any suggestions on how to do this faster?

```
def fillna_with_best(x):
    m = mode(x['c'])
    if m.count[0] > 0:
       x['c'].fillna(m.mode[0], inplace=True)
    return x

df = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).apply(lambda x: fillna_with_best(x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `Series`'s built in `mode` method:

```
df['c'] = df.c.groupby([df.a, df.b]).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iat[0]))
```